# How to search for all files of a particular type and list them?

Tags: android, android-file

Well I have been new to android development and nothing has been so interesting ever since!!
But I just dont understand there are some areas where you just cant help!!
Well I got stuck while implementing a search method which will be called once and it will list all the files of a particular type present in the storage **internal**(sdcard) as well as **external**(ext_card).
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things that you need to do.

In order to filter files based on a type (or an extension), you can use a FilenameFilter like this:

```
public static final FilenameFilter FILENAME_FILTER = new FilenameFilter()
{
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename)
    {
        return filename.endsWith(FILE_EXTENSION);
    }
};
```

As an app, you don't have access to the internal storage, only the external storage (whether that be on an SD card or not, it's still called the same thing.  This can be referenced using

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

Also, be sure that you have the right permissions in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify:

1. You always have access to your app's own internal storage, but you can't search the internal storage of another app.
2. In modern devices, the location of internal and external storage is not always related to the presence of an SD card. Internal storage is always implemented in the device's internal memory. External storage may be implemented on an SD card, but many devices these days implement it in the same internal memory hardware as internal storage. The system, however, separates internal and external storage. If the device has internal and external storage in internal memory *and* an SD card, the card is entirely separate and only stores media files.
3. Although you should use android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, please note that it is not yet being enforced. This is mostly a note for someone who reads this thread and objects to the idea that READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is "necessary".